# Error Code: AccountDidNotSerialize. Error Number: 3004. Error Message: Failed to serialize the account

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, cargo

I am trying to update value of string. I can update if its type is `u8`, `u32`, `u64`, or `i64` but cannot update if it's a string type. Any guesses what am I doing wrong?

Code snippet:

1. Program Function

```
    pub fn set_uri(
        ctx: Context<ModifyLedger>,
        new_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger_account;
        ledger_account.uri = new_uri;    
        Ok(())
    }
```

2. derive Account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ModifyLedger<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub wallet: Signer<'info>,
}
```

3. Account:

```
#[account]
pub struct Ledger {
    pub uri: String,
}
```

Comment: How many bytes of space have you allotted to the Ledger account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I increased the space of my account and redeployed the programs with new keys.

```
#[account(
  init,
  payer = payer,
  space = 82+36,
  seeds = [b"my_custom_seed"],
  bump)
 ]    
 pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>
```

Comment: Hi, iam also facing this same issue 
can u let me know how much max size of space I can provide at space value

Comment: It depends as per you needs. If you don't know how much exact space is required then you can push it to a some higher value like if you have ```space = 82``` you can do something like ```space = 1024```

Comment: Hi, in my current project requirement, I need to store some data of users  who enters to my Dapp,
Before I was only using one PDA account to store all the user details then I was getting serialized Error 3004
Then, I came up with a solution for storing all user details by creating an account for every user, where i can have a n number of accounts in a program

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
#[account]
pub struct Ledger {
    pub uri: String,
}
```

use

```
// Implements an Accounts deserializer on the given struct.   
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ledger {
    pub uri: String,
}
```